# filter items by Site name and List Name using SPSiteDataQuery

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spquery, spsitedataquery

I am listing files from multiple folders using the below code:

```
SPSiteDataQuery q = new SPSiteDataQuery();
q.Lists = "<Lists BaseType='1'/>";
q.Query = "<Where> <Where>
<And><Neq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType'/><Value Type='Lookup'>1</Value></Neq>
<Contains><FieldRef  Name='ProjectProperty.Title' /><Value Type='Text'>Site_Name_Value_From_TextBox</Value></Contains>
</And>
</Where></Where>";

q.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive' />";
q.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' /><FieldRef Name='File_x0020_Type' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='FileRef' /><ListProperty Name='Title' /><ProjectProperty Name='Title' />";
```

the code is working fine for listing items, but i need to filter items by Site name and Library Name, i used

`<Contains><FieldRef  Name='ProjectProperty.Title' /><Value Type='Text'>Site_NAme</Value></Contains>`

but i get no results, when i use Title or FileRef or any other field filter is working fine, what should i use instead of "ProjectProperty" and "ListProperty "??

Comment: Hope this Link is Helpful for you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.webs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<FieldRef Name="SiteName" /><Value Type='Text'>Site_Name</Value>
```

or

```
<FieldRef Name="ows_SiteName" /><Value Type='Text'>Site_Name</Value>
```